# PHP problems with multilanguage

Tags: php, session, multilingual

I have problems with php multilanguage. I'm using function *check_lang* and it works fine in one page, but once I go  to another page the $_SESSION['lang'] variable $lang turns back into default (en). What is the problem?

```
<?php

    function check_lang() { 
    if(isset($_GET['lang'])
        {
        $lang = $_GET['lang'];
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang
        }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'])) { 
        $lang = 'en'; 

    } else { 
        $_SESSION['lang']=$lang; 
      } 

    //directory name 
    $dir = 'languages'; 
    return "$dir/$lang.lng"; 
    } 

    ?>
```

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` before `check_lang()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to:

```
session_start();
```

At the top of each of your scripts in which you want to use session variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call session_start() on each page you're planning on using the $_SESSION[] global in. That's what tells PHP that it should look up the session_id from the user's cookies or the query string so that PHP knows which session's values to use.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).